# Merging my changes on top of already commited changes

Tags: git, github

So this might be a repeated question, but I could not find some resources. Suppose I'm working on a branch A, and I've committed the changes locally and not pushed the changes. Another engineer is working on the same branch and pushed some changes on that branch. There is a merge conflict in some files. How do I make sure I have those changes in my commit before pushing it?

I was hoping I could do a `git pull` and there would be changes on that file, resolve merge conflict and do a `git commit --amend`. But I used `git pull` to pull latest changes but that said the branch has diverged and asking me to merge

Comment: "Another engineer is working on the same branch" Really? Two people pushing commits directly to the same branch?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) so that you're up-to-date with the remote branch. Also pass `--all` if there are multiple remotes to fetch them all.

```sh
git fetch
```

Then you want to do [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). This will rewind your commits, apply the remote changes, then replay your commits. You may encounter merge conflicts during the replay, but you can resolve them without creating new commits.

Assuming your remote is called `origin` and the branch is `develop`:

```sh
git rebase origin develop
```

If there are no merge conflicts, this will just do its thing, and you're good to go.

If there are merge conflicts, just resolve them as they appear. You can just modify the file, then stage it with [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add), and finally continue rebasing.

```sh
git rebase --continue
```

When it prints that you've rebased successfully, you're finished!

---

Rebasing it generally safe, but if you find that you made any major mistakes after the rebase, read up on [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) for how to recover your previous state.

Comment: Might be worth adding an optional “take a backup” step showing how to create a new branch without checking it out before doing the rebase.